# how to set date through protractor

Tags: angular, protractor

I tried with sendkeys but that is not working.
Below is the code during inspect:

```
<input _ngcontent-c10="" class="col-md-6 col-lg-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 mat-input-element mat-form-field-autofill-control ng-pristine ng-valid ng-touched" date="true" formcontrolname="toDate" matinput="" name="toDate" placeholder="To Date" readonly="" aria-haspopup="true" min="2019-12-23" id="mat-input-1" aria-invalid="false" aria-owns="mat-datepicker-1">
<img _ngcontent-c10="" class="img-calendar" src="./assets/calendar.png">
<mat-datepicker _ngcontent-c10=""></mat-datepicker>
```

Comment: `.sendKeys()` is for text inputs. If it's a datepicker element you'd need to pick a date by clicking on the day/month/year you need

Comment: Thanks @JoaquinCasco . It worked by clicking on day/month/year.

Answer (score -1):

It will help to you,
In your .ts file :

```
date = new Date((new Date().getTime() - 3888000000));
```

In html file

```
<mat-datepicker  [startAt]="date" #picker></mat-datepicker>
```